# How can I set one value as "on" and everything else as "off" in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the state of my react app where there are 3 keyvalue pair in the state object. I want to set just one as "on" and the rest as "off".

```
onMenuClick = (leafName) => {

        this.setState(Object.assign({}, {
            news: "off",
            tournament: "off",
            register: "off",
        }, { leafName: "on" }))

    }

import React from 'react'
import './Leaf.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'




const Leaf = ({ leafName, state, onMenuClick }) => {

    return (

        <div onClick={() => onMenuClick(leafName)} className={`leaf ${state}`}>
            <Link className="a" to={leafName}>{ leafName.toUpperCase() }</Link>
        </div>



    )

}


export default Leaf

import React from 'react'
import './Menu.css'
import Leaf from '../Leaf/Leaf'



class Menu extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            news: "off",
            tournament: "off",
            register: "off",
        }
    }

    onMenuClick = (leafName) => {

        this.setState(Object.assign({}, {
            news: "off",
            tournament: "off",
            register: "off",
        }, { leafName: "on" }))

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="menu">
                <Leaf onMenuClick={this.onMenuClick} leafName="news" state={this.state.news} />
                <Leaf onMenuClick={this.onMenuClick} leafName="tournament" state={this.state.tournament} />
                <Leaf onMenuClick={this.onMenuClick} leafName="register" state={this.state.register} />
            </div>
        )

    }

}
export default Menu
```

It's supposed to be menu navigation. If I click on one of them, the one that I clicked should be activated and the rest should be deactivated. And it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the state on a case-by-case basis. It's more to manage than you need.

Store the one that is turned on, and then compare the current leaf name to it when you need to. e.g.

```
onMenuClick = (leafName) => {
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, {
        on: leafName,
    }));
};

const Leaf = ({ leafName, state, onMenuClick }) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => onMenuClick(leafName)} className={`leaf ${leafName === state.on ? "on" : "off"}`}>
            <Link className="a" to={leafName}>{ leafName.toUpperCase() }</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put leafName in brackets in your setState:

```
{ [leafName]: “on” }
```